# Get-Aduser in Powershell cutting off fields

Tags: powershell

I know its out there but can 't seem to get it right, this `Get-Aduser` command is getting the info  need but cutting out fields sometimes(giving me the "...") What am I doing wrong? thx

```
Get-ADUser -f * -Properties *|
    where {$_.enabled -eq $true} |
    ft Name,EmailAddress,*Phone,*Title,GivenName,Surname,Department > D:\UtilityFiles\AD\users.csv
```

Comment: Try using the Out-File cmdlet, this will pipe the actual objects out as opposed to just the text, something along the lines of `... | Out-File D:\UtilityFiles\AD\users.csv` instead of `>`

Comment: Cmdlets like `Format-Table` and `Format-List` are only for display purposes, not for saving data to file, pipeline manipulation, etc.  Just use [Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.2) to send the objects to CSV.

Comment: If you really wanted to see untruncated in the console you could use `$FormatEnumerationLimit = -1` before running your command.  Check just `$FormatEnumerationLimit` first so you know what value to set it back afterwards if desired, but I agree with boxdog... just export the full value to the CSV is probably what you're after.

Comment: Try set-content instead of > or out-file.  Out-file does some extra formatting.  Also select-object instead of format-table.

Comment: I like that Out-File Idea...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Helps you getting the data to the file without cut

`Get-ADUser -f * -Properties *| where {$_.enabled -eq $true} |select-object Name,EmailAddress,*Phone,*Title,GivenName,Surname,Department | export-csv -path D:\UtilityFiles\AD\users.csv  -notypeinformation`

Comment: Brilliant!!! Thank you very much.... I'll be back, now to figure out how to put in Task scheduler..  :)

Comment: that's very easy man, just follow the below URL https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/07/03/how-to-automate-powershell-scripts-with-task-scheduler/

Comment: You're right, that was easier than I thought Thank you Very Much Again... Hope you have a great rest of your day/night...